# I am trying to write a batch file to go through a list of computers search for Adobe Flash and return the PC name and version of Flash

Tags: batch-file

This works to pull the version of Adobe but I cant seem to figure out how to get the host name display next to the Adobe version number.

`PSINFO @C:\vulns.txt /s | find /I "Adobe Flash Player" >> Results.txt`

I tried:

`PSINFO @C:\vulns.txt /s | find /I "System Information for \\","Adobe Flash Player" >> Results.txt` with no luck.

I think it needs to be done using a for command echoing the %Hostname% just not sure if that is right or how to do it. Please help I have 191 workstations I have to go through and find out which ones are on outdated version of Flash Player.

Comment: What is `psinfo`? And how does the line you want to find look like?